# render layout: false still loading the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My rails version is 4.1.6

I have the following action:

```
def create_modal
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { layout false }
    end
end
```

I also tried variations such as just `layout false`, `render layout: false` etc. But it still renders with the layout.

I don't see what I am missing.

Comment: How about `format.html { :layout => false }`?

Comment: No difference, still loading layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just under the controller definitions:

```
layout 'application', only: [:create_modal]
```

solves the problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you are rendering.
This will render the file that is usually rendered, but will not include.the layout.

```
Render :file => "", layout => false
```

Comment: Try giving :layout => false to the controller. What happens when you do that?